# What is the area size of Skull Island in the King Kong (2005) movie?

Tags: dinosaurs, king-kong

The Skull Island in the 2005 version of *King Kong* is very unique: it is an ecosystem of primordial creatures that are battling for food, space, and their ecosystem on a sinking island. The wide variety of creatures including the "neosaurians" is made clear, though the island seems to be filled with too many such creatures.

Many other media that show "lost world" settings in modern times often depict the region filled with known species of dinosaurs, which is unlikely as millions of years of evolution in an ever-changing environment would change the dinosaurs and the species as a whole into something else.

But my main question is what is the area size of the Skull Island in the 2005 version of the movie? Just curious to know!!!

Comment: Alligators, sharks, lobsters and many many insects have all been around as they are now since dino times and will probably continue right until after human times.  What most people think of as evolution is a branch off then an extinction of the classic breed.  Extinction is natural and happens often, but it is not ascertained in nature.

Comment: Lions and tigers and bears **and frikkin' dinosaurs**, oh my!

Answer (score 5):

There are two scale maps in the *[The World of Kong: A Natural History of Skull Island](https://www.amazon.co.uk/World-Kong-Natural-History-Island/dp/1416505199)* factbook, based on the film. The [first](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/speculativeevolution/images/b/be/Skull_island.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160704181204) advises us that it's 1:50000 (e.g. 1cm = 500 meters). Later in the same book we have a simplified topographical map set to the same scale with a scale in cm below it.

Skull Island is shown to be **approximately 14.5km x 19km** giving it a total area (including sea) of 275 sq km. Approximately 33% of this area is land, giving a rough *land area* of 100 sq km, equivalent to the island that forms the British Overseas Territory of [Monserrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Caribbean_islands_by_area#Islands_10%E2%80%9329_km2_(3.9%E2%80%9311.2_sq_mi))

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image]

([Source](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/f6/44/ccf644602e200c6f5021d97b43c729d6.jpg)) On this map, the wall measures 24 miles.

[image]

([Source](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/14/40/991440ccc6c7045577df43b273d049fa.jpg)) The wall is destroyed.

[image]

([Source](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pyZyJ75cQ0w/Urd91ozv1FI/AAAAAAAACik/Nla-scXMvkg/s1600/Shrinking+Skull+Island.jpg)) Island evolution.

Comment: When posting an anwer here, please ensure that you answer the actual question asked. In this case, the question asked how large Skull Island is in terms of its surface area, and you didn't answer that. Also, it would've been better to include the images you posted links to within the answer itself, so that the information would be preserved within the answer even if the links stop working at some point. Furthermore, you didn't clarify whether those images are from an official source or not.